# UserDetailsService bean missing since Spring Security migration from XML to JavaConfig

Tags: spring-security, spring-java-config

I use Spring Security `3.2.0.RELEASE`.

I am currently migrating my application's XML-based Spring Security configuration to a *JavaConfig*-based Spring Security configuration.

In the old `security.xml`, I configured a *JDBC*-based `UserDetailsService` like this:

```xml
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder" />
        <!-- parsed by JdbcUserServiceBeanDefinitionParser -->
        <!-- the following creates a JdbcUserDetailsManager -->
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Among other effects, above XML configuration **automatically registered a Spring Bean of type `JdbcUserDetailsManager`** <sup>(a subtype of `UserDetailsService`)</sup> that I could inject into other components like so:

```java
@Service
public class MyCustomService {

    @Inject
    private JdbcUserDetailsManager judm;

    //...
}
```

---

My *JavaConfig*-based adaption of above XML looks like this:

```java
@Configuration
// @ImportResource("classpath:to/no/longer/needed/security.xml")
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
            .jdbcAuthentication()
            .passwordEncoder( somePasswordEncoder )
            .dataSource( someDataSource );
    }

    // ...
}
```

Above JavaConfig configuration **does not seem to additionally register a Spring Bean of type `JdbcUserDetailsManager`**. This means that `MyCustomService` does not get injected with such a bean, and therefore I get a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`:

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
```

Using the JavaConfig approach, how can I get hold of a bean of type `JdbcUserDetailsManager`?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add

```
@Bean
public JdbcUserDetailsManager jdbcUserDetailsManager(){
    return new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
}
```

to your SecurityConfig class?